# Backpack trip to Europe

Tags: europe, international-travel, solo-travel, backpacking

I am planning my first backpack trip to Europe. I have 8 days before going back to work. I am planning the itinerary as follows:

Starting Amsterdam 2 days
2 days Paris 
2 days Barcelona 
2 days Madrid

My trip will be from 24 Dec to 1 Jan. Does this make good sense or shall I drop a city. Also, I want to know how shall I plan my commute from one place to other. Is it safe to travel single in these places? Can someone guide me?

Comment: Are you in good shape and accustomed to whirlwind touring? You may hit the wall midway through Barcelona, but that's an OPINION.

Comment: Hi. This is an extraordinarily broad question that pretty much boils down to asking us to plan your trip for you. You'll likely have better luck if you ask specific detailed questions after you've done some research about your options.

Comment: @GayotFow Yes I am in a good shape as of now. Does Barcelona requires a lot of whirlwind touring?

Comment: @ZachLipton I have done a bit of research about Paris and Amsterdam. Paris to Barcelona is one of my travel concerns. I want to ask that is the itinerary doable in the mentioned days. Have I assigned more/less days to a place?

Comment: That looks too ambitious for a backpack tour -- you will spend most of the time travelling! If I were you, I would choose two of those cities, and enjoy them.

Comment: It's not that Barcelona is particularly arduous, it's more to the fact that it's the third locale in 5 days. And the Paris-Barcelona leg is blowing a whole day on the train. You will be burned out and start hitting the wall. While you can be physically present in 4 - 5 cities in 8 days, it's squandering your experience. More realistic is A'dam 2 days, Strasbourg  or Brussels 2 days,  Paris 4 days (including a day out to Chartres or Versailles and back).  But that's an OPINION!

Comment: Amsterdam to Strasburg is not an easy/fast/cheap travel. I would suggest Antwerp, Brussels or one of the North France cities.